# Trying to validate information based on security rights

Tags: sql, vb.net, record

Trying to make certain textboxes on my webpage visible based on the rights a user has from a user rights table I have

Here's my stored procedure being called

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uc_OneAPortalUserAccess]
    @intUserID as INT
    ,@intInvoiceShipmentID as INT

AS

BEGIN

SELECT TOP 1
    i.InvoiceShipmentID, p.ProjectID, OneA.UserID, OneA.ViewAccess, OneA.EditAccess, OneA.ApproveAccess

FROM 
    KitUnit ku
    JOIN ProjectAccount pa on pa.ProjectAccountID = ku.ProjectAccountID
    JOIN Project p on p.ProjectID = pa.ProjectID
    JOIN InvoiceShipment i on i.InvoiceShipmentID = ku.InvoiceShipmentID
    JOIN OneAPortalAccess OneA on P.ProjectID = OneA.ProjectID
    JOIN Users U on U.UserID = OneA.UserID
WHERE 
    i.InvoiceShipmentID = @intInvoiceShipmentID
    and OneA.UserID = @intUserID

END
```

Here is my vb.net code

```vb
Dim blnView As Boolean
Dim blnEdit As Boolean
Dim blnApprove As Boolean
Dim sqlp(1) As SqlParameter

sqlp(0) = DataBase.CreateSQLParam("@intInvoiceShipmentID", SqlDbType.Int, intInvoiceShipmentId)
sqlp(1) = DataBase.CreateSQLParam("@intUserID", SqlDbType.Int, intUserID)

DataBase.ExecuteNonQueryParam( _
       "uc_OneAPortalUserAccess", _
       CommandType.StoredProcedure, _
       sqlp)

'If user has view only access
If blnView = True Then
    btnSaveTop.Visible = False
    btnSaveBottom.Visible = False
    btnApproveBottom.Visible = False
    btnApproveTop.Visible = False
End If
```

I don't know how to pull back my access fields and display them

Comment: Well you can't get any results if you are doing an non query call-- I expect you want to do a query so you can get some results back.  To know for sure we would need to see the object definition for DateBase object.

Answer (score 0):

I used a pattern that is more familiar to me. Keeping the database objects local allows you to control that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this chore.

I created a `DataTable`, `Connection` and `Command`. Then Executed a DataReader to `Load` the `DataTable`. The values that appear in you Select statement will be in the `DataTable`.

I do not like to mix User Interface code with Data Access code. This `Sub` could be a `Function` returning an instance of an Approval class or structure. I suspect you have included the UI code for brevity.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode(intInvoiceShipmentId As Integer, intUserID As Integer)
    Dim blnView As Boolean
    Dim blnEdit As Boolean
    Dim blnApprove As Boolean
    Using dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("uc_OneAPortalUserAccess", cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@intInvoiceShipmentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intInvoiceShipmentId
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@intUserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intUserID
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            blnView = CBool(dt.Rows(0)("ViewAccess"))
            blnEdit = CBool(dt.Rows(0)("EditAccess"))
            blnApprove = CBool(dt.Rows(0)("ApproveAccess"))
        Else
            blnView = False
            blnEdit = False
            blnApprove = False
        End If
    End Using
    'If user has view only access
    If blnView = True Then
        btnSaveTop.Visible = False
        btnSaveBottom.Visible = False
        btnApproveBottom.Visible = False
        btnApproveTop.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```